# Add linebreak with jQuery at end of each textarea row

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, line-breaks

So I have been googleing around for a couple of days but I have not found a solution so far, so I'm turning to you guys with hope that there even is a possible solution for this.

I need to, at the end of each line in a textarea add a linebreak before it is sent to PHP. That is, even if the user does not press enter but if a word get's cut of or it just jumps down a row because it has filled the with of the textarea. And I need to do so with jQuery or Javascript.

Does anyone have any good ideas on how to do so?

Thanks!

**Update:** Keep in mind that I also need to send the text via a json encoded string with Ajax to PHP. I should have mentioned that!

Comment: You should consider users' pressing ENTER key and use PHP's `nl2br` function.

Comment: The problem you're going to have is that different browsers will wrap the words in different places, even with a fixed width on the textarea. Why not just break it yourself every so many words?

Comment: @Sarfraz It will be dynamic input from the users, and so there is no control over that.

Comment: @davidethell I could do that, not on word but on character count, but it would cut off words so I would have to build something that tests if words can fit on one row and then move the whole word etc. Feels unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/r7JBe/2/

Comment: Hey this was just what I needed, I didn't want to write this kind of script myself right now but thanks, it works perfectly. @Mubix

Answer (score 1):

Textarea element has COLS attribute, which means maximum number of characters per line. Browser will jump the word that includes the (COLS+1)th character. You could write a piece of javascript that roughly does something like this.

- Have a counter to calculate characters since last linebreak.
- Loop through the string character by character.
- If you see a linebreak, reset counter.
- If you see a 21th character since last linebrak (or beginning), go backwards until you see beginning of the word (space for example) add linebread and reset counter and continue.
- Else increase counter

Notice that wrapping the line is part of the browsers logic, so if you want it exactly as in browser, you may have to research every browser (for example what they consider as word-break).

Answer (score 0):

There's a little known attribute called `wrap` for `textarea`s. It's not in the standard though, so your browser compatibility mileage may vary. Go to http://jsfiddle.net/nj3cG/ with chrome and submit the form while watching the network tab in chrome's dev tools. You'll see newlines in what gets sent with the form

[image]

http://www.abiglime.com/webmaster/reference/html/tags/textarea.htm

```
<textarea wrap="off|physical|virtual|hard|soft">
```

**Description**

The wrap attribute is used to define how text will wrap in the text box. Possible values:

- `off` disallows word wrapping
- `physical` allows word wrapping and send the text with line breaks in tact when transmitting the data using scripting. Can also be called `hard` in some browsers
- `virtual` show word wraps in the box but sends the data as one long string of text when transmitting the data with scripts. Can also be called `soft` in some browsers